# Codename one create a PIN constraint

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

Am creating a form with some Text inputs where a user can update their PIN, so i need the inputs to be only numeric and also kind a password- masked.
I've tried this here but it only makes the input masked and accepts even characters,

```
TextComponent currentPIN = new TextComponent().labelAndHint("Current Pin").constraint(TextArea.NUMERIC).constraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);
        TextComponent newPIN = new TextComponent().labelAndHint("New PIN").constraint(TextArea.NUMERIC).constraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);
        TextComponent confirmPIN = new TextComponent().labelAndHint("Confirm PIN").constraint(TextArea.NUMERIC).constraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);
```

how can I achieve this, I want the input to accept only PIN, that's numeric and be masked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot chain calls to `constraint()` that way and have them add up.

From the Javadoc (my emphasis):

> ```
> public void setConstraint(int constraint)
> ```
>
> Sets the constraint which provides a hint to the virtual keyboard input, notice this doesn't limit input type in any way!
>
> Parameters:
> constraint - one of ANY, EMAILADDR, NUMERIC, PHONENUMBER, URL, DECIMAL it ***can be bitwised or'd with one of PASSWORD***, UNEDITABLE, SENSITIVE, NON_PREDICTIVE, INITIAL_CAPS_SENTENCE, INITIAL_CAPS_WORD. E.g. ANY | PASSWORD.

The proper form is

```
...constraint(TextArea.NUMERIC | TextArea.PASSWORD)
```